# Visual Studio 2019 - No Attach to Process Type option for Docker (Windows Container)

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-2019, windows-container

I have a bunch of containers running .Net Framework Apps on Windows Containers. Apps work great, containers work perfectly. I need to debug some code on one of the containers using VS2019 and according to this article it should be easy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-process-running-in-docker-container?view=vs-2019

Unfortunately, I only see "Docker (Linux Container)". I do not see an option for "Docker (Windows Container)" and I don't see any additional steps needed in the articles or any other to enable this.

I can confirm that my Docker Desktop is switched to Windows Container and everything is working perfectly I just don't see this option but seems like I should be able to. Has anyone come across this and found a solution? I saw some stuff for installing a remote debugger on the container but again the article does not say this is a prerequisite. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing the same issue, the answer is to upgrade your visual studio 2019 instance to the latest. I noticed I was on 16.4.x. I upgraded to 16.8.3 and the options all appeared and worked as expected. Apparently the options for Windows containers and the new WSL 2 based engine are only available in 16.5.x and above. Hope this helps someone out.